# Program that takes a word than searches and prints out the whole string that contains the word

Tags: java

The basic function of this program is to take a word and search in an array of strings than search and print the string containing that word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = {"I am Alive.", "Are you dead?", "Let's see if it works."};
    String search;
    int count=0;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter word");
    search=s.nextLine();

    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        //check strings individually
        if(str[i].charAt(i)=='.'||str[i].charAt(i)=='?'){   //search for dot or any sentence finisher
            count++;
        }
        if(str[i].contains(search)){
            System.out.println(str[count]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know what the `break` keyworkd does? if it is not aviable in the first array element, it will stop the loop and print `Not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not break the loop there since it is only considered not found once you went through all the sentences in the array. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str={"I am Alive.","Are you dead?","Let's see if it works."};
    String search;

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter word");
    search=s.nextLine();

    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(str[i].contains(search)){
            System.out.println(str[i]);
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out that `break`, it's executed always.

Check this:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {    
  final String[] strings = { "I am Alive.", "I am Alive...too.", "Are you dead?",
      "Let's see if it works." };
  int found = -1;

  System.out.print("Enter search term > ");
  try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
    final String input = scanner.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; (i < strings.length) && (found < 0); i++) {
      if (strings[i].contains(input) && (strings[i].contains(".") ||
          strings[i].contains("?"))) {
        //System.out.println(strings[i]);
        found = i;
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.printf("%s%n", (found >= 0) ? strings[found] : "Not found");
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using a `boolean` instead of an `int` in this case.

Comment: it works but i am not able to understand what StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() did here I consulted http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html but it didn't help much

Comment: @UmaKanth I'm printing the result based on `found`; it's (more) semantically correct to use a `boolean` since `-1`, `0` and all that stuff tends to be confusing, but it came handy in this example. Initially, I was using a `boolean` but since I wanted to print the result outside the `for-loop`, the "found element index" was not available at that scope anymore...but good point!

Comment: @ahsanarif You can specify (or not) the charset that you want to use with `Scanner` and the bytes from the stream will be converted into characters using the specified charset; as I always use UTF-8 (unless I can't), I tend to specify it. Have a look at the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-)